# Checkboxes for every section playing different behavior

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery Code where I am using it to check/uncheck the checkboxes. they work somewhat good but i want to do some changes which i am stuck how to?

Here is my working piece of code:

i have seperate sections where each section has its own set of checkboxes, so what i am doing is:

```
$(document).on('click','.section',function() {
    var lstofids = [];
    $("input[data-section='"+$(this).data('id')+"']'").each(function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked') {
            $(this).attr('checked','false')
        }else{
            $(this).attr('checked','true');
            listofids.push($(this).attr('data-section');
        }
        $("#lstoffields").val(lstofids);
    });
});
```

the code above works, but here are the few caveats i am struggling with

1. It adds the items to the textfield named as lstoffields as comma separated only when a button having a class name of .section is clicked.
2. I want to rename the button which its checked all it should be "uncheck all" and when unchecked, it should be checkedall" - like toggling
3. single click of checkboxes is not working, even if i do click, i am unable to add the value to the lstodfields text field. same case is with removal
4. if i check 2 and try to click the button it toggles the remaining with checking and the checked with unchecking - it should be consistent that is not happening

Comment: Can you share your html structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.section', function() {
  var isCheck = $(this).val() == "Check All";
  $("input[data-section='" + $(this).data('id') + "']").prop('checked', isCheck);
  var listofids = $("input[data-section='" + $(this).data('id') + "']:checked").toArray().map(x => $(x).val());
  $("#lstoffields").val(listofids);
  $(this).val(isCheck ? "Uncheck All" : "Check All");
  resetButton();
});

$(document).on('change', '.chk', function() {
  var listofids = $("input[data-section='" + $(this).data('section') + "']:checked").toArray().map(x => $(x).val());
  $("#lstoffields").val(listofids);
  resetButton();
});

function resetButton() {
  if ($('.chk:checked').length > 0) {
    $("#btn").removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $("#btn").attr("disabled", true);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn" disabled> Action</button><br/>
<input type="button" data-id="1" value="Check All" class="section" /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" data-section="1" value="1" class="chk" /> 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" data-section="1" value="2" class="chk" /> 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" data-section="1" value="3" class="chk" /> 3<br/>
<input type="text" id="lstoffields"></input>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, exactly what i am looking for: One last caveat Left is there s a button outside the scope of the section which is currently disabled and and it is for each section and i want to activate it when i check any checkbox within a section so i can do it its homework